# Hide the footprint of CasperJS with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to hide the utilisation of CasperJS with one my script. Currently I'm trying to change the resolution, the user agent and the language with that :

```
casper.userAgent("My UA");
casper.viewport(1600, 900);
casper.page.customHeaders = {'Accept-Language': 'fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3'};
```

The casper.viewport() and casper.page.customHeaders doesn't seem to work with Google Analytics... When trying on some websites, it seems to be okay, but Google Analytics gets to see I'm a web scraper :

```
My lang is "c"
Compatibility with JAVA : no
Screen resolution : 1024x768
Flash version : not set
```

Is there anything I can do to fake this ?

**(Piece of) Solution**

Thanks to kasper pedersen, here is a part of the solution :

We can override some variable during the initialize part with :

```
casper.on('page.initialized', function (page) {
    page.evaluate(function () { 
        (function() {
            window.screen = {
                width: 1600,
                height: 900
            };
            window.navigator.__defineGetter__('javaEnabled', function () {
                return function() { return true; };
            });
        })
    });
});
```

This fakes the windows resolution and the plugin for Java. To fake the flash plugins, we could do something like that :

```
casper.on('page.initialized', function (page) {
page.evaluate(function () { 
    (function() {
        window.screen = {
            width: 1600,
            height: 900
        };
        var fake_navigator = {};
        for (var i in navigator) {
          fake_navigator[i] =  navigator[i];
        }
        fake_navigator.javaEnabled = function() { return true; };
        fake_navigator.language = 'en-US';
        fake_navigator.plugins = {
            length: 1,
            'Shockwave Flash': {
                description: 'Shockwave Flash 11.9 r900',
                name: 'Shockwave Flash',
                version: '11.9.900.117'
            }
        };
        window.navigator = fake_navigator;
    })();
});
});
```

When doing this and verifying the info in the window.navigator of PhantomJS, everything seems okay, but Google Analytics doesn't track me as a visitor any more (I don't appear in the real time window of Google Analytics...).

So I just fake the first two info, and for the language, I fake it in changing the language of my server (`export LC_ALL=en_US.utf8`).

Comment: I've never run into this problem how do you know they view you as a scraper?

Comment: I scrape a webpage that only me know and see the result in Google Analytics.

Comment: Why didn't you post this piece of the solution as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to kasper pedersen, here is a part of the solution :

We can override some variable during the initialize part with :

```
casper.on('page.initialized', function (page) {
    page.evaluate(function () { 
        (function() {
            window.screen = {
                width: 1600,
                height: 900
            };
            window.navigator.__defineGetter__('javaEnabled', function () {
                return function() { return true; };
            });
        })
    });
});
```

This fakes the windows resolution and the plugin for Java. To fake the flash plugins, we could do something like that :

```
casper.on('page.initialized', function (page) {
page.evaluate(function () { 
    (function() {
        window.screen = {
            width: 1600,
            height: 900
        };
        var fake_navigator = {};
        for (var i in navigator) {
          fake_navigator[i] =  navigator[i];
        }
        fake_navigator.javaEnabled = function() { return true; };
        fake_navigator.language = 'en-US';
        fake_navigator.plugins = {
            length: 1,
            'Shockwave Flash': {
                description: 'Shockwave Flash 11.9 r900',
                name: 'Shockwave Flash',
                version: '11.9.900.117'
            }
        };
        window.navigator = fake_navigator;
    })();
});
});
```

When doing this and verifying the info in the window.navigator of PhantomJS, everything seems okay, but Google Analytics doesn't track me as a visitor any more (I don't appear in the real time window of Google Analytics...).

So I just fake the first two info, and for the language, I fake it in changing the language of my server (`export LC_ALL=en_US.utf8`).

Answer (score 7):

The language settings is a bit odd, but the screen resolution is probably "wrong" because you're setting the viewport, not the screen res. AFAIK Google Analytics uses the `window.screen`-object.

I haven't worked with CasperJS, but in Phantom you could do this:

```
page.onInitialized = function () {
    page.evaluate(function () {
    window.screen = {
            width: 1600,
            height: 900
        }
    });
};
```

I think Java is checked using `navigator.javaEnabled()` and Flash is looked up in `navigator.plugins`, so something similar could be done for Flash and Java.

Comment: Perfect, exactly the answer I was expacted. I have modified my script but not checked it yet in Google Analytics, however everything seems okay.

Comment: After a lot of test, your function to change the window.screen works, but not the one to change navigator.plugins and navigator.language : these functions are read-only, and `__defineGetter__` didn't work. Moreover, I've try to change my locale on my machine (LC_ALL), but I always have the "C" locale.

Comment: I think Phantom allows you to override the whole `window.navigator` object, if you do it during `onInitialized`. But you have to replace the whole `navigator` object, not just certain properties. Checkout Phantom's example for detecting browser sniffing: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/detectsniff.js